# Return list of users

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I have entity like this

```
{
  id,
  projectId,
  name,
  age,
  address
}
```

Now I need to return list of users that are connected to projects which have 4 or more users
For example if I have in database records like this

```
{1, 1, "John", 21, "Address1"}
{2, 1, "Joey", 22, "Address2"}
{3, 2, "Tom", 25, "Address3"}
{4, 3, "Mike", 23, "Address4"}
{5, 1, "John", 26, "Address5"}
{6, 3, "Jane", 28, "Address6"}
{7, 2, "Joe", 23, "Address7"}
{8, 2, "Steve", 24, "Address8"}
{9, 3, "Will", 29, "Address9"}
{10, 1, "Robert", 21, "Address10"}
{11, 2, "James", 20, "Address11"}
```

i should get returned list

```
{1, 1, "John", 21, "Address1"}
{2, 1, "Joey", 22, "Address2"}
{3, 2, "Tom", 25, "Address3"}
{5, 1, "John", 26, "Address5"}
{7, 2, "Joe", 23, "Address7"}
{8, 2, "Steve", 24, "Address8"}
{10, 1, "Robert", 21, "Address10"}
{11, 2, "James", 20, "Address11"}
```

because project with ID 1 have 4 users and also project with ID 2 have 4 users, but project with ID 3 have 3 users and I don't need that users as result.

I'm using SpringData JPA but as I researched JPA doesn't provide option to make such filtering and as other option I found that I can write custom MySql Query but don't know how that query should look like
I've tried something with group by `projectId` but don't know how to count and get only groups that have 4 or more users

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM USER u GROUP BY projectId", nativeQuery = true)
List<User> findUsers();
```

Comment: Try this SQL query.SELECT COUNT(projectId), name, projectId
  FROM <TABLE_NAME>
 GROUP BY projectId
HAVING COUNT(projectId) >= 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table temp (
  id int,
  projectId int,
  name varchar(20),
  age int,
  address varchar(20)
);


insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address) values (1, 1, 'John', 21, 'Address1');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address) values (2, 1, 'Joey', 22, 'Address2');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address) values (3, 2, 'Tom', 25, 'Address3');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address) values (4, 3, 'Mike', 23, 'Address4');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address) values (5, 1, 'John', 26, 'Address5');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address) values (6, 3, 'Jane', 28, 'Address6');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address)  values (7, 2, 'Joe', 23, 'Address7');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address)  values (8, 2, 'Steve', 24, 'Address8');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address) values (9, 3, 'Will', 29, 'Address9');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address) values (10, 1, 'Robert', 21, 'Address10');
insert into temp (id,projectId,name,age,address)  values (11, 2, 'James', 20, 'Address11');
```

**QUERY :**

```
SELECT *
FROM   temp
WHERE  projectid IN (SELECT projectid
                     FROM   temp
                     GROUP  BY projectid
                     HAVING Count(*) > 3)
```